# How do I convert the binary data back to image after i upload it to mongo db

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, binary, pymongo

How do I convert the image back from the binary data after I querying it please.
this image is to be shown on a web page

name = request.form['name']

```
        pic = request.files['img']
        
        filename = pic.filename
        def allowed_file(filename):
            return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
        
        if allowed_file(filename):
            
            
            pic.save(os.path.join(application.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            
            image = upload_folder +  "/" + filename
            
            with open(image, "rb") as f:
                encoded = Binary(f.read())
            
            coll.insert_one({"filename" : filename , "image" : encoded , "name" : name})
```

Comment: Can you fix your formatting please?  Don't use leading spaces,  use triple backtick to delineate code

Comment: Excuse me...How is this related to my problem..I want to make the image ready for render..in png format